# How to make internal update checkbox default checked at insights section at case details page in suitecrm 8

Tags: php, angular, suitecrm

I’m trying to achieve that by default whenever I **create a case/edit a case/update a case** internal update checkbox should be checked on the insights section, which is coming from AOP_Case_Update module.

I've looked for any option in studio. But the option in studio is for case details section internal update checkbox not for the insights section.

I've searched in google, whatever the options I got it's no use.
I’ve tried to override the verdefs, by taking suggestions from the below link.
[reference link](https://community.suitecrm.com/t/cases-view-internal-update-checkbox-cannot-set-default-value-to-on/26016/4)

but didn’t work.
Attaching a screenshot so, it will be clear what I want to achive. I'm using suitecrm 8 for my project.

[image]